# Floyd–Warshall algorithm on undirected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, shortest-path

I am referring to the algorithm from the Wikipedia page on the [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

In case of undirected graphs should I change the assignment statement inside the `if` condition to

```
dist[i][j] = dist[j][i] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
```

or they are equivalent?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I thought that they are equivalent.

Comment: "They"? Hint: Can you ever have `dist[i][j] != dist[j][i]` in an undirected graph?

Comment: You can save slightly less then half of memory (strictly saying `(n * (n - 1)) / 2`) for undirected graph by trade-off with slightly complicated indexing (and, therefore, runtime).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every undirected graph can be represented as directed graph by replacing every edge $(i,j)$ with 2 edges $(i,j); (j,i)$. And if you're running Floyd–Warshall algorithm on such directed graph - it would work correctly, as always.

Comment: It does not work correctly if the undirected graph has a negative edge.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this algorithm is so amazing that it works for both directed and undirected graph.

Only one thing you should keep in mind while storing distances at (i,j) you should do the same for (j,i).

`graph(i,j) = graph(j,i) = distance`

Rest algorithm will work fine and you only need to do:

`dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]`

Comment: Not really so amazing -- an undirected graph is just a special case of a directed graph in which the edge relation is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

I think for undirected graph the `Floyd-Warshall algorithm` can be optimized. The speedup should be `2`.

```
            for(INTTYPE k = 0; k < num_nodes; k++) {
                for(INTTYPE i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
                    INTTYPE distki = (k<i)?dist[k][i]:dist[i][k];
                    if(k == i || distki == INF) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    for(INTTYPE j = i+1; j < num_nodes; j++) {
                        INTTYPE distkj = (k<j)?dist[k][j]:dist[j][k];
                        if(k == j || i == j || distkj == INF) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        WEIGHTTYPE via = distki + distkj;
                        if(via < dist[i][j]) {
                            dist[i][j] = via;
                            prev[i][j] = k;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The optimization comes in the inner-most loop(`for(INTTYPE j = i+1; j < num_nodes; j++){ }`). It only calculates one half of the matrix.